# Twilio Calls: Is it necessary to verify numbers for making twilio calls after getting verified account

Tags: twilio

Is it Required to Verify receiver numbers on twilio for making calls after the account has been verified?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Once you've upgraded your account you will not be required to verify any of the outbound numbers you want to call or text to.

Have a look at [this article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mate :) Will check it out.

Comment: Hi Marcos, I have another question, is there any API available to download the recorded calls with the CALL SID or RECORDING SID available for a particular call?